# Rails 3, sqlserver, using set_primary_key, and inability to find with a specific ID

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, odbc

I'm trying to port a Rails2 application over to Rails3 - this app provides a front-end to multiple databases, one of which is SQL Server 2005.  The SQL Server 2005 database is legacy so I have to use set_table_name and set_primary_key as such:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "SpiraTest.TST_PROJECT"
  set_primary_key "PROJECT_ID"
end
```

Firing up the console I can see

```
irb(main):002:0> Project.primary_key
=> "PROJECT_ID"
irb(main):003:0> Project.table_name
=> "SpiraTest.TST_PROJECT"
irb(main):004:0>
```

I can even use Project.find(:first), Project.find(:last), etc. and retrieve the data. What I can't do is find using an id, like this:  Project.find(1).  I get met with:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:317:in `find_one'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:292:in `find_with_ids'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in `__send__'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in `find'
        from (irb):4
irb(main):005:0>
```

I have been looking down through the finder_methods and can see where in the find_one method that

```
  record = where(primary_key.eq(id)).first
```

'primary_key' is nil.

I'm at a loss on this - I'll continue to hunt and see what I find.

Gems being used for completeness:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'mongrel'
gem 'psrutil'
gem 'net-ldap'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'ruby-odbc'
```

Comment: It doesn't even get to generating SQL because it cannot determine the name of the primary key to look for.

Comment: Sorry about that. Read too fast. I have a very similar setup. But I'm using Rails v3.0.3 and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter v3.0.9 and doing a simple find works.

Comment: I'm finding myself suspecting the table_name setting. Rails is going to want to escape the table_name and the primary_key. Is it possible within your setup to simply say "set_table_name 'TST_PROJECT'?

Comment: Interesting - I fixed the version number of activerecord-sqlserver-adapter to 3.0.9 and it works (didn't need to do anything with the set_table_name or set_primary_key values).  I need to go back and look up the previous version of adapter I was using (3.0.15 I believe) and see what could have gone amiss.

Comment: That. Is. Bizzare. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use set_primary_key and note, it is case sensitive.